# Bash catch input and cd to it

Tags: bash, debian

I am trying to make a bash script that will catch the inputs of a user who runs it. The inputs will be along the lines of the name of the destination and source directories. The source directories are in a layout of hourly.#, daily.# and monthly.#. The inputs will catch like hourly.33 and change to that directory to copy all the of contents of that folder to the destination. There is a total of 2 destinations that can be chosen but have 55 different sources. I am not wrapping my head around enough using the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
### Modify below this ###
srv1=/home/minecraft/test/rr1server2
srv2=/home/minecraft/test/rr2server2
srv3=/home/minecraft/test/rrlobby2
### DO NOT MODIFY BELOW THIS ###
while true; do
    read -p "Are you sure you want to start the rollback?:" yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* )
            while true; do
                read -p "Which server? 1, 2 or 3:" srv
                    case $srv in
                        [1]* )
                            while true; do
                                read -p "Which backup? Input only hourly.#, daily.# or monthly.#:" rollback
                                cd $rollback
                                cp -Rp * $srv1
                                echo "Rollback Complete!"; exit;;
                        [2]* )
                            while true; do
                                read -p "Which backup? Input only hourly.#, daily.# or monthly.#:" rollback
                                cd $rollback
                                cp -Rp * $srv2
                                echo "Rollback Complete!"; exit;;
                            esac
                        done
                        [3]* )
                            while true; do
                                read -p "Which backup? Input only hourly.#, daily.# or monthly.#:" rollback
                                cd $rollback
                                cp -Rp * $srv3
                                echo "Rollback Complete!"; exit;;
                            esac
                        done
                    exit;;
                esac
            done
        exit;;
    esac
done
```

I get the following

```
minecraft@cronus:~/test$ ./rollback.sh
./rollback.sh: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
./rollback.sh: line 21: `                                                               echo "Rollback Complete!"; exit;;'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do think that you have discovered that with the current structure of that program it is getting harder to debug.

Therefore I think it is rime to start using functions by now.
This is your program spit up in functions, almost all of it is still your code.

Now new functionality I'm afraid, but a lot easier for debugging :-)
(and indeed I found some)

```
#!/bin/bash

### Modify below this ###
srv1="/home/minecraft/test/rr1server2"
srv2="/home/minecraft/test/rr2server2"
srv3="/home/minecraft/test/rrlobby2"
### DO NOT MODIFY BELOW THIS ###

RollBack()
{
    while :
    do
        read -p "Which backup? Input only hourly.#, daily.# or monthly.#:" rollback
        cd "$rollback"
        cp -Rp * "$1"
        echo "Rollback Complete!"
    done
}

WhichServer()
{
    read -p "Which server? 1, 2 or 3:" srv
    case "$srv" in
        [1]* ) RollBack "$srv1" ;;
        [2]* ) RollBack "$srv2" ;;
        [3]* ) RollBack "$srv3" ;;
    esac
}

while : 
do
    read -p "Are you sure you want to start the rollback?:" yn
    case "$yn" in
        [Yy]* ) while true; do WhichServer; done ;;
    esac
done
```